# Cummulative matrix multiplication on successive square arrays in an (M,M,N) or similar array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

Say I have N MxM arrays in a single MxMxN array.  Is there any simple way in numpy to do a cummulative matrix multiplication of successive MxM arrays (the MxMxN array can be overwritten).  I can do it with a loop as shown below but I'm wondering if there is a better way?  Note the ordering MxMxN is not special, I could just as easily have NxMxM or something.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(4).reshape((2,2))
n=3
b = np.dstack((a,)*n)
print(b[:,:,0])
#[b[:,:,k].dot(b[:,:, k - 1], out=b[:,:, k]) for k in range(1, n)]
for k in range(1, n):
    b[:,:,k] = np.dot(b[:,:,k], b[:,:,k-1])
    print(b[:, :, k])
```

From which I get the output:

```
[[0 1]
 [2 3]]
[[ 2  3]
 [ 6 11]]
[[ 6 11]
 [22 39]]
```

I also tried the following list comprehension which failed:

```
[b[:,:,k].dot(b[:,:, k - 1], out=b[:,:, k]) for k in range(1, n)]
```

**EDIT:**
I'm intersted in all the intermediate results so b[:,:,0], b[:,:,0] x b[0:,:,1], b[:,:,0] x b[0:,:,1] x b[:,:,2], etc. not just the final b[:,:,0] x b[0:,:,1] x ... x b[:,:,N-1]

Comment: I don't think there is anything that will do what one would wish `np.dot.accumulate` did. But unless `M` is very small and `N` very large, your Python loop, no matter how slow, is going to have a negligible effect on the overall performance, which is going to be dominated by the actual multiplications.

Answer (score 2):

For a M*M*N array, how about:

```
reduce(np.dot, np.rollaxis(b, 2))
```

For Python 3 you need to import `reduce` from `functools`.

Comment: Do you know of any way to do it without reduce?

Comment: @rtrwalker no I can't think of a good alternative other than the loop you already have..

Comment: @rtwalker Why don't you like the reduce? It is an elegant solution once you have the index of the `MxM` array at the first position, hence the `rollaxis`.

Comment: I do like the reduce. It is just that various python style guides say 'Use for loops instead of reduce' so I was just wondering if there was some other equally elegant way.

Comment: reduce only gives me the final result.  I'm intersted in all the intermediate results so b[:,:,0], b[:,:,0] x b[0:,:,1], b[:,:,0] x b[0:,:,1] x b[:,:,2], etc. not just the final b[:,:,0] x b[0:,:,1] x ... x b[:,:,N-1].  I have edit my question to make this clear.